# How communicate between application same network by wifi?

Tags: android, http

I want to share data between application in the same network. I create json objects to share, i don't know if http request(POST) between devices on my code will works? How do you listen all time?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless your devices both have a web server running (which is quite unlikely) you won't be able to use the HTTP protocol. However, you could use [Websockets](https://proandroiddev.com/websockets-with-scarlet-7d3e2235dc03) to exchange data directly between devices if they are on the same LAN.

Comment: Hello, i found https://github.com/Lekky71/android-server-app    ; How can i use HTTPS protocol instead HTTP in my local network?

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to have web servers on Android phones ? If I refer to the original question, exchanging data between devices via wifi, having web servers on each client **is not a good solution**.